How to authenticate herself to the openai api service when using URLExecute?
I have tried the canonical example (with the real API Key)
  apiEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
  apiKey = "myAPIKey1234567";

  (*Create the payload for the POST request*)
  payload = 
    ExportString[<|"model" -> "gpt-4", 
      "messages" -> {<|"role" -> "user", 
      "content" -> "What is the weather in Prague today?"|>}
          , "max_tokens" -> 50, "temperature" -> 0.7
      |>, "JSON"
     ];

  (*Perform the HTTP POST request*)
  response = 
    URLExecute[
     apiEndpoint, {"Method" -> "POST", 
      "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "application/json", 
        "Authorization" -> "Bearer " <> apiKey}, "Body" -> payload}];

however the Mathematica 13.2 returned the error message

URLExecute::nvldarg: The argument Content-Type->application/json should be a string

But what is the correct way to send send authentication in the required format?

This does not seem to be the way to set headers with URLExecute. Try URLExecute @ HTTPRequest[....
